# What is the format for public keys to create Azure VMs?

Tags: openssl, azure

I have an openssl public key file.
I converted it to PEM format for azure.

However, when i try to create an azure vm with it, it gives me this msg:

```
The certificate is in an invalid format. X.509 standard format in a .cer or .pem file is supported.
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Update:**
This is how the top line of my .pem file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: How is your cert looking like? (Don't post the full, only the first line with `--- BEGIN CERTIFICATE..` and the type of characters used.

Comment: @sebix updated post with first line

Comment: Thats a public key, not a certificate ;)

Comment: @sebix ok so am i supposed to put public key inside an x509? what is the command for that?

Comment: You have to create a certificate e.g. OpenSSL has a parameter `-key` for usage of an existing (You also need the matching private key to do that).